# what is difference between file descriptor and fildes

Tags: c, linux

What is fildes and in linux, what is the difference between file descriptor and fildes. For example, the below write deals with file descriptor

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

Where as the below pwrite deals with fildes

```
ssize_t pwrite(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are just parameter names. They both refer to file descriptor.

Read manual for those functions

```
man 2 write
man pwrite
```

Answer (score 1):

generally In functions like

`foo(int a, int b);` or `foo1(int x, int y);`

no need to ask that what is `a` and what is `x` (by simply seeing the declaration ). 
So consider the type only , name associated with type is just identifier in the parameter list which is used inside the function.

In your case both `fd` and `fildes` are file descriptors.